# Android Virtual Device cannot startup

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm trying to launch an `AVD` from the `Android Virtual Device Manager` but for some reason it cannot go thru.

My goal is to deploy my `Hello World` application developed with `MSVS2015Pro/C#/Xamarin` on this `AVD`.

What is the best configuration for this `AVD` in order to deploy `Xamarin.Android` applications?

Below you have an screenshot with part of the configuration I have for this `AVD`.

[image]

Then when I try to start the application (`not from the C# IDE yet`, but with the `Start` button on the `AVD Manager`), I get the following error:

[image]

Any idea on how to make this `AVD` get started and then run `Xamarin` applications on it?

Comment: Better to use Genymotion https://www.genymotion.com/
It is much faster and have more performance.

Answer (score 0):

- you can user Genymotion,just Google it
- do in AndroidStudio like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7I37.png)
- and this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQGU3.png)

Comment: I'm new on this world, so I have three questions: 1- Is Android Studio gonna be discontinued soon because Microsoft recommends to use Visual Studio? (please, check this [link](https://www.xamarin.com/faq#xpq6)). 2- Which is better for mobile development: Android Studio or Visual Studio?. 3- If I want to develop also for iOS is recommended use Android Studio (is it possible develop for iOS there?)?

Comment: -  android studio may not support develop for ios ,

Answer (score 0):

AVD is usually very Slow.
before you go further, Just try Genymotion, or BlueStacks.
I suggest BlueStacks, its easy-to-use and fast.